# Creating a Tab to my Facebook Page

Tags: tabs, facebook-iframe, facebook-canvas

I want to add a site map tab onto my facebook page, it keeps saying my domain is not valid for some strange reason, also when i go and see my tab on face book its telling me the Connection is Untrusted.

what am i doing wrong?
here the link i want to add to an tab

https://staffy-bull-terrier.co.uk/fbpage/sitemap.html

Comment: You can't just tell the browser that you have an SSL Certificate by typing "https" before your domain.

Comment: I see now that you have a redirect to http://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/ ... whoy would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because you are trying to add a http secure link with a certificate that does belong to other domain!

Comment: i owne this website how do you get an SSL Certificate?

Comment: First of all do not redirect the link you are trying to add. As said before i still see the redirect. You should ask your hosting provider to install you a SSL certificate. Mind that you have to buy a trusted certificate from a recognized authority like VeriSign for your domain.

Comment: I just look it up i would have to pay another £10 year sod that i would rather go without i pay enough out already i dont make anything from my website and forum. i'm just going to do an page on my website instead and just post when people are looking for information.

Comment: why don't you try to add the link via `http` and not `https` ?

Comment: i get this error when i remove the s
Error

Secure Canvas URL must use SSL and begin with https.

Comment: As of Oct 2011, facebook now requires you to get a real SSL cert (you can get them for cheap at GoDaddy.com and they have the best support around) installed onto the webserver.  As mugur said, you should get one installed to fix the issue

Comment: I dont really want to pay more toward my hosting. i will just have to go without another tab.